# Generating a Fixed alpha + sequential numeric values in python

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am trying to workout a method where in my models would have a field that has a structure like: "ITEM1", where in the numeric part would increase sequentially and be unique eg: "ITEM2", "ITEM3", and so on. I am not sure how to achieve this. Please point me in the right direction.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For default Django models use AutoField as `id`. It's autoincremented. And you can write a property for your model to return the result you are expecting:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    @property
    def item_name(self):
        return f'ITEM{self.id}'

my_model_instance1 = Model.objects.create()
my_model_instalce1.id = 1
my_model_instance1.item_name = 'ITEM1'

my_model_instance2 = Model.objects.create()
my_model_instalce2.id = 2
my_model_instance2.item_name = 'ITEM2'
```

I think it's redundant to store it in DB, but if you want you can do it with:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=255) 

    def item_name(self):
        return f'ITEM{self.id}'   

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.item:
            self.item = self.item_name()
        super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the quick reply, am trying to add it as the default value to a charfield in the model like so `item = models.CharField(max_length=255, default=item_name)` but the values are not getting stored, am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Please look at my edited answer.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked like a charm!!!!!!!!!